# A value of a model is always undefined but the json api is not

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In an Ember 1.13.3 application I have this simple model :

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  link: DS.attr('string'),
  acquired_skills: DS.hasMany('users', { async: true, inverse: 'acquired_skills' } ),
  searched_skills: DS.hasMany('users', { async: true, inverse: 'searched_skills' } )
});
```

And I have this route :

```
import Ember from 'ember'

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    console.log(this.store.find('skill', 1).get('name'));
    return this.store.find('skill');
  }
});
```

A request is sent at `/skills/1` and this is the result :

```
{"skill":{"id":1,"name":"Ember","description":"JS Framework","acquired_skills":[1],"searched_skills":[1]}}
```

In the console, 'Ember' should be written but I have `undefined`.

Why I have no value for the name of the skill?

I have the same behaviour for all models and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This returns a promise:

```
this.store.find('skill', 1)
```

When you do `.get('name')`, it hasn't finished doing the ajax request. Instead try this:

```
this.store.find('skill', 1).then(function(skill){
  console.log(skill.get('name'));
});
```

Comment: When I do this, there nothing on the console. I followed [the guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/models/working-with-records/).